# Effective divisor on a curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves

I was reading the online courseware by MIT on Arithmetic Geometry and I came across this paragraph:

> Let $C/k$ be a (smooth, projective, geometrically irreducible) curve of genus $1$ over a perfect
> field $k$. Let $n$ be the least positive integer for which Div$_k C$ contains an effective divisor $D$ of
> degree $n$ (such divisors exist; take the pole divisor of any non-constant function in $k(C)$, for
> example). If $C$ has a $k$-rational point, then $n = 1$ and $C$ is an elliptic curve.

I do not understand why does such an $n$ exist when Div$_kC$ is the free abelian group generated by the points of $C$, and thus we can obtain any effective divisor of any degree. Furthermore, what does the parenthesized part mean? And the final sentence seems to suggest that if $C$ does not have a $k$-rational point, then $n$ must be greater than $1$.

Comment: You should really give a link to the notes where you read this. Presumably $\operatorname{Div}_k(C)$ is defined somewhere in those notes, and I think that definition would answer your question.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn Ok I'll take note of it, thanks for the example too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q1:** $Div(C)$ is generated by the **closed** points of $C$.

For example if $p$ is a closed point of $C$ with residue field $L(\supset k) $, then $\deg[p]=[L:k].$ So $\deg[p]>1$ if  $[L:k]>1.$

**Q2:** Let $f\in k(C)^*$, a non-constant rational function on $C$, then the $$div(f)=(f)_0-(f)_{\infty}.$$ In particular, $(f)_{\infty}$ is the divisor (hence pole divisor) associated to the poles of the rational function $f$, which is effective. Now $(f)_{\infty}\neq 0$, precisely because $f$ is non-constant. So you can take its degree that will be a positive integer.

**Q3:** If $C$ does not have a $k$-rational point, then (as seen in answer to Q1 above) for a closed point $p$ with residue field $L\supsetneq k$, $\deg[p]=[L:k]>1$.

Comment: So in some sense, $k$-rational points are closed points but, over an algebraically closed field, these points coincide right? Why would $(f)_\infty \neq 0$ if $f$ is nonconstant? We can choose $f = f_1(X)/f_2(X)$, where $X = x_1,...,x_n, f_2(X)=1$. Or do we need matching degrees between $f_1$ and $f_2$?

Comment: @KelvinLian Yes, for algebraically closed field $k$, the closed points are $k$-rational points. If for every rational function $f$ on $C$, $(f)_{\infty}=0,$ then $k(C)=\Gamma(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$, but $C$ is proper implies $\Gamma(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra which is a field. Hence  $\Gamma(C, \mathcal{O}_C)$ is a finite field extension of $k$. So all rational function on $C$ will be constant.

Comment: Ok thank you, one last thing that is bugging me: so suppose $C$ does not have a $k$-rational point, you've already shown that a closed point $p$ will have degree greater than 1. But the "effective divisor of degree $n$" that the paragraph is talking about, seems to imply that this divisor $D$ is just a closed point of $C$ right? Otherwise, if say, $D = ap_1 + bp_2$ for positive integers $a,b$, then deg $D = n$ will be greater than deg $p_1$ and so $n$ won't be the least positive integer. But pole divisors need not be simply of the form $D = p$.

Comment: @KelvinLian A pole divisor may not be of the form $D=p$. But it will be a positive linear combination of closed points. Existence of one such a non-zero pole divisor, will show that the set of natural numbers appearing as a degree of an effective divisor on $C$ is non-empty. Now by well ordering property of natural numbers, this set will have a least element (that is your $n$).

Comment: Ok, thank you for your explanation and time.

Answer (score 2):

No, $\operatorname{Div}_{\overline{k}}(C)$ is the free abelian group generated by the $\overline{k}$-points of $C$; $\operatorname{Div}_{{k}}(C)$ consists of those divisors in $\operatorname{Div}_{\overline{k}}(C)$ that are invariant under the action of $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$. For instance, consider the affine plane curve $C: x^2 + y^2 = -1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $C$ has no $\mathbb{Q}$-points, then there is no divisor of degree $1$ in $\operatorname{Div}_{\mathbb{Q}}(C)$. However, the degree $2$ divisor $(0, i) + (0, -i)$ is in $\operatorname{Div}_{\mathbb{Q}}(C)$.